# Inconsistent information in Google Cloud: the project exists and does not exist the same time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I recently created my Google cloud project with command `!gcloud init` at Google Colab.

But I can't see it in projects list:

```
!gcloud projects list

PROJECT_ID             NAME              PROJECT_NUMBER
xxx-xxx-xxx      My First Project       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I also can't find it at https://console.cloud.google.com/
But the other information says that the project exists:

```
!gcloud projects describe [PROJECT_ID]

createTime: '2020-07-19T14:45:34.074Z'
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: xxxx-xxxx
projectId: xxxx-xxxx
projectNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

```
!gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT-ID]

bindings:
- members:
  - user:<my email>
  role: roles/owner
etag: xxxxxxx
version: 1
```

```
!gcloud info

...
Account: [<my email>]
...
```

How can I resurrect my project from space between the living and the dead?

Comment: Is it possible you have different credentials? What happens if you `gcloud projects list --account=<my email>`?

Comment: The `gcloud init` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init) is used for initial setup of gcloud and to create new or reinitialize gcloud configurations. Could you elaborate on the steps you followed to create your project with `gcloud init`?
Could you share with us any documentation that you may have followed? 
Also could you try running the `gcloud config set [Project-ID]`[command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) and let me know the output?

Comment: @DazWilkin this command also doesn't show my project, but "describe" command still says that project exists and I am owner

Comment: I'm able to repro the behavior.... that's sure curious!

Comment: I recommend you file a bug using Google's [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). Google does shard projects (e.g. Cloud and Apps Script) **but** it doesn't make sense in this context. I wonder whether colab(oratory) is applying metadata incorrectly on project creation that does not correctly enable the project's inclusion when using `gcloud` or cloud console.

Comment: FYI: tzovourn removed the sensitive information from your post but scrubbing it from the edit history will take moderator intervention. I've already raised a flag but wanted to let you know that anything in your post after the first 5 minutes is in the history is in the history for your question without help from a diamond mod.

Comment: Sorry, the command is `gcloud config set project [project-id]`. Please run it and check if it works. If it does, then also please try to find your project as per [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#listing_projects). If it doesn't, then report this issue through the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for further investigation.